# Probability of retirement event

Tags: probability

This is elementary, but not clear to me.

Suppose I know that the mean age of retirement is $\mu$ and the standard deviation $\sigma$.
What is the probability that someone of age $x$, who has not yet retired, 
will retire sometime in the next year,
i.e., between $x$ and $x+1$?

Clearly for small $x$, far below the mean, the probability is near zero, and for large $x$, it approaches $1$.  So it is a type of cumulative distribution...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do we know that he has not retired yet?

Comment: I assume you want some bound on the probability.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yes. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X \in [x,x+1) \vert X \geq x) & = \dfrac{\mathbb{P}(X \in [x,x+1))}{\mathbb{P}(X \geq x)} = \dfrac{F_X(x+1) - F_X(x)}{1-F_X(x)}\\
& = 1 - \dfrac{1-F_X(x+1)}{1-F_X(x)}
\end{align}
Since you have not clarified if you are looking for a bound on the probability, this is what we get.

Comment: Thanks, but: (a) What is $F$? (b) Why is it not possible to compute the probability exactly? Apologies for my ignorance...

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of the retirement age. The probability you wish to compute will depend on the cumulative distribution function, though it might be possible to obtain bounds in terms of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ (like in the case of Chebyshev's inequality, for instance).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke You can compute the exact value of the cdf of a Gaussian using Gauss's error function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function. Any decent language defines it.
@ user17762 Isn't it weird that your last quantity tends to 0 when x tends to infinity?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn Actually, it is not weird. It the term becomes $\dfrac00$ and hence no conclusion can be made as such.

Comment: @user17762 You are right. My mistake :) I plotted the function `1 - (erfc(x+1)./erfc(x))` just to see the tendency :) It tends to 1, not 0: http://postimg.org/image/78ixttsut/

Comment: @user17762 and Sh3ljohn: Thank you!  I need to think about this more before replying substantively...

Comment: Here is an example. If $\mu=70$ and $\sigma=5$, then $F(76)=0.88$ and $F(75)=0.84$, and your expression yields $0.25$. So there is only actually a small chance that this 75-yr-old will retire, whereas I would think it would be larger. An 80-yr-old only has a 39% chance of retiring. Maybe the normal distribution assumption is the culprit here.

Answer (score -1):

Integrate the Gaussian probability density function from x to x+1